# .NET core 3 API, develop on Mac with Visual Studio Code: how deploy and configure on IIS?

Tags: c#, macos, iis, .net-core, webapi

I developed a web API with .Net Core 3 on Mac with Visual Studio Code without problem.
I publish with command: 

`dotnet publish -c release`

But I cannot deploy on IIS: 
the publish command doesn't generate any "web.config" file, so I use this configuration I found on web (maybe is for Core 2.0?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
                  arguments=".\thenameofmydll.dll"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

My "program.cs":

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }

         public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                }); 
    }
```

My questions:

- the "program.cs" is correct to work with IIS?
- the "web.config" is correct?

I found several example on web, but all of this are partial or incomplete... so sorry if I ask for something previously asked, but I cannot found a full example for .Net Core 3

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce what you said. `web.config` is generated even on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [asp.net core document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/):

> When the -r parameter is omitted, an executable is created for your current platform.

I suggest you could try to set the runtime version in the command and try again. It will add the web.config file.

```
dotnet publish
 -c Release
 -f netcoreapp3.1 
-r win-x64
```

Besides,any NuGet packages that have platform-specific dependencies for the targeted platform are copied to the publish folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are [Microsoft documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) available for .Net CORE 3.x application deployment in IIS.
In short first you need to install the [Hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) for .Net core 3.x in IIS server.
Then you can publish the application as a self contained application or a framework dependent application. You can select this option when you setup the publish settings.

Your web.config should be something like this

```
<configuration>
   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
     <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" 
         resourceType="Unspecified" />
       </handlers>
       <aspNetCore processPath=".\<app name>.exe" 
       stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" 
       />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```